# iOS Google Auth: "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password"

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, email, authentication

My app has three login options: email, google, and facebook, all via Firebase. Everything works perfectly except for logging in eith email.

#### Recreate the problem

---

1. Create a user with email (first name, last name, email, password), (lets say with the email, test1@gmail.com)
2. Sign out and return back to login page
3. Sign in with google using the same email (test1@gmail.com)... this will give an alert that says that a user already uses that email. It does not redirect user to the home screen.
4. Sign in with email again (same email and password)
5. User cannot sign in now. User is shown the warning that "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password"

In Firebase Authentication, the user who used to have an email sign next to it now has a Google sign next to it. However, in Firestore, the firstName, lastName, email, password, and uid is still stored.

#### My code

---

**Sign in with Google**

```
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
                
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully logged into Google")
        
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        // sign user in with Firebase
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            let firstName = user?.user.displayName
            let email = user?.user.email
            let lastName = ""
            let uid = user?.user.uid
            
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            } else {
                // Successfully logged in
                print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google email: ", email ?? "", "Now add user to Firestore if user is new.")
                
                // check if user already exists
                self.addUserToFirestore(firstName ?? "", lastName, email ?? "", uid ?? "", "Google")
                    }
                })
            }


    func addUserToFirestore(_ firstName:String, _ lastName:String, _ email:String, _ uid:String, _ signInMethod:String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
        // check if user exists in firestore
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {
               if document.exists {
                let message = "Good news! You already have a Coal account that uses " + email + ".\nPlease sign in to your existing account. Then you will be able to link your " + signInMethod + " profile from your Account Settings page."
                // user exists. send to chats screen.
                print("User already exists. Document data: \(String(describing: document.data()))")
                self.showError("You're already a member!", message)
              } else {
                // user does not exist. create a new user
                 print("Document does not exist. Create new user.")
                
                docRef.setData(["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "email":email]) { err in
                    if err != nil {
                        // Show error message
                        print("Error saving user data to Firestore")
                    } else {
                        print("New user created in Firestore")
                        self.transitionToConvo()
                    }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Sign in with email function**

```
        // Signing in the user
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                // Couldn't sign in
                self.loginErrorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                self.loginErrorLabel.alpha = 1
  
            }
            else {
                
                // user signed in successfully, go to TabBarController
                print("User signed in")
                
                let tabBarC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController") as! TabBarController
                tabBarC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(tabBarC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("Switched to TabBarController")

            }

        }
```

**Sign up with email**

```
            // Create the user
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
                // there is an error creating user
                if err != nil {
                    self.showErrorLeft("There was an issue creating your account.\n\nPossible reasons for this isssue:\n1) Your email is not formatted correctly.\n2) You already have a Coal account that uses " + email + ". Please sign in to your existing account.\n\nIf you think this is a mistake, please contact as at coal.britto@gmail.com.")

                }
                else {
                    let uid = result!.user.uid
                    // User was created successfully, now store the first name, last name, email
                    print("new email created in firestore", uid)
                    db.collection("users").document(uid).setData(["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "email":email, "password": password, "uid":uid]) { err in
                        if err != nil {
                            // Show error message
                            print("Error saving user data to Firestore")
                        } else {
                            print("New user created in Firestore")
                            self.transitionToConvo()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Transition to the chats screen
                    self.transitionToConvo()
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are authenticating across multiple providers. There's a section in the documentation that covers it [Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking). It looks like you've read that but where is [EmailAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking#email-password-sign-in)?

Answer (score 0):

A User signing in with Google on an E-Mail address that already exists as an E-Mail/PW User will not throw an error. Instead the user is transitioned into a Google Signin User.

So the behaviour you experience is intended by Firebase.
The reason why the password etc. is still stored in your firestore database is because you dont overwrite it with the new data in your code.

Your code after a Google signin sees that there is a document for that user already (the one you created in your `createUser` function) so nothing happens in your db.

---

*NOTE: Please do not store clear text passwords in your database.*

Comment: Is there a way to allow the user to sign in with email/pw AND Google? I don't want Google Sign in to overwrite the password, otherwise the user will be unable to sign in again. Also, I'm just storing clear text passwords right now for testing.